# What arthropod is in the picture?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I am from Philippines and I found this in my room.

This arthropod has 6 legs and have a bit long Chelicerae like spiders that can fold to hold its food. It's about half an inch long. It also looks like a
scorpion but I could not find anything like it on the internet. Thank you!

I've also noticed that it can jump and it also produced spider silk.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is not a pseudoscorpion as those would have 8 legs and then the two front large pincers. This is most likely a kind a jumping spider where the two large front legs count as two of the 8 legs.

Depending on your geography (not given in the question), this looks to resemble a jumping spider in the genus **Chalcolecta** (or some regional variant of that based on where you are). Hard to see any detail (like eyes and body segments) from your photos. But have a look at some of these and see if any of them match your specimen. Here are some pics of C.prensitans and C.simon.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is actually the closest one. I noticed that it can jump and produces silk like a spider. However, the tip of its abdomen does bend sometimes.